# How to get usernames to show in chrooted SFTP?

Tags: sftp, chroot

Under normal SFTP, I see owner and group usernames.  Under chrooted SFTP (via `internal-sftp` in `sshd_config`), I see numeric user IDs for owner and group.

What do I need to do to get usernames to show up?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  Had to create hard links to `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` and then the mapping took place as expected.

I plan on creating specialized versions of these files for regular users so that they see something reasonable.